# Where can I get gcc.exe (compiled) version 4.7.0?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction

At gcc website compiled file (.exe) of gcc version 4.7.0 is not available. MinGW has upto 4.6.2 version. Where can I get compiled gcc.exe version 4.7.0 ?

Comment: There's a precompiled version [here](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html)

Comment: If you've got GCC 4.6.2, you could download the source of 4.7.0 and build it for yourself.  It won't be very hard; it'll take a couple of hours compilation time.  OTOH, you could download the version that @Szabolcs points you at, which should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: You could check out [mingw-w64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/), I linked to some personal builds.

Comment: As previous people already written... but here is yet another link: 
ftp://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/sourceware.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-4.7.0/

Comment: Thanks guys, you are so fast. I received the answers from you within minutes.

Answer (score 7):

There is a fairly frequently updated version of MinGW gcc, compiled for Windows, [here](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html).  It includes several precompiled libraries (such a boost) which make it quite useful for learning.  Currently it has gcc 4.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

For GCC compiler binaries look at http://www.gnupit.org

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.